# Finding columns with same headers and merging and centre headers only

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data set in which I have data of several department over different months. I want to bring the same departments together and merge the department name across all months.
Data set:
http://bit.ly/1JRfyiz
Output:
http://bit.ly/1Cr9Q4c
There can be any no. of departments and any no. of months(I means max 12 months).
I am not able to figure it out how to merge only headers with same name.
Please tell me what I should do in order to get output I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I am not able to figure it out how to merge only headers with same name."

OK, then I assume you have already figured out how to do the first part ("bring the same departments together") and your input has the columns sorted properly.

The idea to merge is then to go from A1, see what department is there, check how far does this department go, merger and start from next cell with another department.

```
Sub trymerge()

'Variables to know where you are
Dim start As Integer
Dim endc As Integer
start = 1
endc = 1

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Loop through all columns where top cell is nonempty
Do While Worksheets(1).Cells(1, start).Value <> ""
  'Loop to find columns next to each other with the same dept name
  Do While Worksheets(1).Cells(1, start).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, endc).Value
    endc = endc + 1
  Loop
  endc = endc - 1

  'Merge what you found

  Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, start), Cells(1, endc)).Merge
  Worksheets(1).Cells(1, start).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
  'Move to next dept
  start = endc + 1
  endc = start
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. For putting columns with same header I sorted the whole data by header row. So, department with the same name come together.